# Highlighting text in the UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a menu item called `Highlight` which calls the below function. The function changes the colour of the selected text and works fine. However, I'm not sure I'm doing it correctly. I am worried that performance problems may occur if the `_myTextView` (an `UITextView`) has large amount of text.

Could you have a look at it and suggest a better way if exist?

```
- (void)highlight {

    NSRange selectedRange = _myTextView.selectedRange;

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]        
                              initWithAttributedString:_myTextView.attributedText];

    [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
                      value:[UIColor redColor] 
                      range:selectedRange];

    _myTextView.attributedText = attributedString;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't cause performance issues since you aren't doing anything too heavy. Even with a large amount of text, UIKit will handle this well. This is as easy as just adding a large amount of text and testing on the device to see how it handles it.

I will suggest you start referring to your objects as self.myObject instead of _myObject. This is because if you ever need to override the getter, you'll have to go back and fix your code to use the getter instead.